# How to pass multselected js variable value to php variable

Tags: javascript, php

```
.bind('dpClosed',function(e, selectedDates) {
        console.log('You closed the date picker and the ' // wrap
            + 'currently selected dates are:');
        console.log(selectedDates);
        var ll=document.getElementById('ll');
                        ll.value=selectedDates;

    }
);
```

I want pass `selectedDates` variable into php variable

Comment: Please format the code properly

Comment: What do you want to do with the "php variable" after assigning the value?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pass a variable values to serverside from frontend is either form submission or using ajax.

Because these two runs at different places if you have a page you can't assign a js variable to php because php run at server and it already ran way earlier before page load.

You have to use ajax or form submission for this:

```
$.post('the/url/to/post', {selectedDates:selectedDates}, function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

Now at php you can get it with:

```
$_POST['selectedDates']
```